# Using Regex to find pairs of words out of a list of words

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words such as:

```
l = """abc
dfg
hij
jih
gfd
cba
cbd
jip
gfe
jiw
cbw"""
```

I want to find pairs of words out of this list,
so the first word is:

```
.(.)(.)
```

And the second word is:

```
\2\1.
```

So the \1 and the \2 refer to the characters in the first word.

The best regexp that I could come up with is:

```
re.findall('(^.(?P<A>.)(?P<B>.)$)(?=.*(^(?P=B)(?P=A).$))', l, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

But this search returns only some of the pairs (because findall returns only non-overlapping results...).
Then I thought of using positive lookbehind assertions, but they can only be used with strings of fixed length...

Is there a way to so this with regex?

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between the pairs of words, in words rather than just with an example? I think you may have lost some precision. Are the words always exactly 3 letters long as illustrated?

Comment: In your sample data, `abc` could be paired with `cba`, `cbd`, or `cbw`.  Do you have a preference?  Or do you want to get all of them?

Comment: @Alan: Obviously he wants to get all of them, otherwise the regex approach would work.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: No. The words in the list can be at any length. The only relationship between the pair of words are the characters that repeat between them. The example I gave looks for two words that apply the patterns - `.(.)(.)`,`\2\1.`.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that regular expressions are a good way to do this (especially in Python, were you can't simply get all possible ways of matching a string like in Perl, so you'd have to call `findall` on all prefixes of your string). A straightforward alternative would be:

```
words = l.split()
pairs = set(frozenset((w1, w2)) for w1 in words for w2 in words 
                      if w1[1:] == w2[1::-1])
```

Results in:

```
>>> map(tuple, pairs)
[('hij', 'jip'), 
 ('abc', 'cbd'), 
 ('dfg', 'gfd'), 
 ('dfg', 'gfe'), 
 ('jiw', 'hij'), 
 ('hij', 'jih'), 
 ('abc', 'cbw'), 
 ('abc', 'cba')]
```

You could also solve this really fast by saving the prefixes of the words in a dictionary in a first pass and then build up the associations in a second pass:

```
from collections import defaultdict

prefixes = defaultdict(list)
for w in words:
    prefixes[w[1::-1]].append(w) 
pairs = set(frozenset((w1, w2)) for w1 in words for w2 in prefixes[w1[1:]])
```

The performance of this will be hard to beat by a regular expression engine.

Comment: Assuming that I have a very long list of words, isn't using regex (if it's possible...) faster than using a list comprehension that goes over the list twice?

Comment: @ItaiS: I doubt that very much, the lookup dictionary solution is O(n). The kind of NFA I have in mind that a regular expression engine would create would have quadratic runtime, because it doesn't know anything about the semantics of the problem. Have you benchmarked?